# how to open usb drive on my virtualbox installed in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, usb, virtualbox, windows-7

I have Ubuntu 14 as host os. And I have installed VirtualBox inside ubuntu.
Now as a guest OS i have installed windows 7. And i want to access USB drive inside this Guest windows 7.

please guide me to follow the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Settings --> USB, and make sure that its enabled.  Then add the USB device that you want making sure that its connected, and click OK.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your virtual machine , click on settings , then in the `USB` tab check the `Enable USB controller`.